# Insert into sql database one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Guys I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. I have a problem inserting records into a one to many relationship database. The scenario is as follow, I have a technician table(techid,name,surname) and a skill table(skillid, skillDesc, techid). The skill table has a techID foreign key.

How can i create a sql statement/procedure to insert a technician with multiple skills assigned to the technician?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Is techid in technician an identity (auot inc) column?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you are facing? The question as written looks very general. the MS documentation for insert in sql-server is  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: You have to do the insert into the technician table first, then the skill table. You may be able to do funky multi-table inserts, but that's probably too fancy

Comment: The question seems to me: How to I pass several skills to one technician to a stored procedure. I don't know myself, but also I wonder why it is not done one by one. Insert into technician and then one by one insert into skill table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have three tables: Technician(techid, name, surname), Skill(skillid, skillDesc), and Ability(skillid, techid). If you only have two tables, each mapping of a skill to a technician would have to include a copy of the skillDesc, which is redundant information. Instead, you want to tables to define the Technician objects and the Skill objects, and a third table to capture the relationships between them.

First execute this query:

```
insert into technician values (my_id, my_name, my_surname)
```

then loop over the skills (psuedocode):

```
for skill in skills:
    insert into Ability values(skill, my_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need three tables Technician, Skill and TechnicianSkill. Using two tables you can not assign multiple skills to a single technician. ( IF TechID and SkillIDs are primary key )

```
Technician Table:
Columns: TechID, Name, SurName

Skill Table:
Columns: SkillID, SkillDesc

-- Put the TechID and SkillID as a foreign key in this table
TechnicianSkill Table:
Columns: TechID, SkillID 
-- You can make a primary key by using the two columns (TechID,SkillID)
```

Comment: This is necessary for a many to many. Not necessary for a one to many. Organizationally this is the way to do it, since you would reference a single skill instead of having to type out the same description every time. Also, don't forget constraints.

Comment: Why include the third column `TechSkillId` in the TechSkill table?  Just make the table include the `TechID` and `SkillId`. Those two fields would be the natural key on the table.

Comment: Thanks for the posts, but it think my question was rather vague. The problem I am having is when the "User" adds a technician, he can then assign more than one skill to the technician. If "Insert technician" is pressed. The program should then call a insert into procedure which then inserts the Technician with all the skills assigned to the technician. However the problem i am facing is to actually insert the technician and the skills simultaneously into the database, and if an error occurs the transaction should rollback.

Comment: @MarcelPalm you have to post your code, so that we can help you

Comment: At the moment I can insert a technician with mutiple skills assigned to the technician, but if an error occur for some reason the transction will only be parcialy completed. So the problem I am facing is writing a stored procedure which will insert the technician, get the technician ID(using max) and then inserting the skills assigned to the technician and if something somewhere goes wrong then the transaction should roll back and nothing should be inserted.